# how to remove multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have some array

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => MOUSE
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 1
                  
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => LAPTOP
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                  
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => PHONE
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    
                )
           
        )

)
```

i need to remove "0" values from the array so the result should be.

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => MOUSE
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 1
                )   
        )
)
```

how to remove it with a dynamic code ? because it will execute large of array. an i stuck in it for days

Answer (score 2):

This `filterArray` function should work.

It just cheks the arrays inside the main array you submit (which in this case is $array["data"]), then checks the third position in each child array, and returns it if the value is not zero.

```
$array = array(
    "data" => array(
        array(
            "0" => 1,
            "1" => "MOUSE",
            "2" => 0,
            "3" => 1
        ),
        array(
            "0" => 2,
            "1" => "LAPTOP",
            "2" => 0,
            "3" => 0
        ),
        array(
            "0" => 4,
            "1" => "PHONE",
            "2" => 0,
            "3" => 0
        )
    )
);

function filterArray($elem) {
    if (is_array($elem)) {
        return (bool) $elem[3];
    }
    return false;
}
    
$array["data"] = array_filter($array["data"], "filterArray");

var_dump($array);
```

Here the output for your array:

```
array(1) {
    ["data"] => array(1) {
        [0] => array(4) {
            [0] => int(1)
            [1] => string(5) "MOUSE"
            [2] => int(0)
            [3] => int(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this community the official language is English. Maybe you thought you were on Stack Overflow en Espanol. Could you translate your answer to English?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I will!

Comment: @Cmen then you have an error on your side, or your array structure isn't what you pasted here. This answer works fairly well.